# Oracle RAC 11g R2 DB silent install: parameter needed for system class

Tags: oracle, installation, rac

I'm installing Oracle RAC DB 11gR2 using response file and silent mode. The installation is failing with the error message:

> [INS-35421] This options installs a single instance database only
>   You have chosen to perform a Desktop class install on a cluster. This options will not install oracle RAC

Which parameter is needed for a server-class install? I tried changing the value for `oracle.install.db.config.starterdb.control` from `DB_CONTROL` to `GRID_CONTROL`, but I still get the same warning.

Answer (score 1):

Try using these 3 options :

```
oracle.install.option=INSTALL_DB_SWONLY \
oracle.install.db.InstallEdition=EE \
oracle.install.db.isCustomInstall=true
```

Comment: Hi Toze and welcome to the site. Can we get you to add a bit of commentary as to _why_ this would be helpful? That would certainly help others coming along after!